# Is there any potential vulnerability in using an unsigned theme on Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows-8, themes, desktop-customization

Assume the patching utility is trusted.  I'm trying to understand whether this limitation is a matter of Microsoft controlling branding or an actual security concern.

As an aside, the hoops I have to jump through to get white title bar text are ridiculous.